# Select children depends on Parent Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

How do i get on change child selection according to the parent selection use js or jquery.

```
<select id="country">
<option value="1">United states</option>
<option value="2">United kingdom</option>
<option value="3">France</option>
</select>

<select id="country">
<option value="">Select country first</option>
</select>
```

If user selected United kingdom (value = 2) should load regions of UK only otherwise it should say "Select country first".

Comment: sorry, can't understand you

Comment: Almost [7000 answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dpopulate+select), none of them worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i found complete tutorial and example code. [LINK](https://www.formget.com/jquery-select-change/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your dependent select a different id, I chose `cities` for this example, and you need to create a map of cities that correspond to the `country` values. Add an onchange event listener to the parent that updates the dependent select's options with the relevant cities. Here is a simple example:

```js
var cityMap = {
    "1": ['New York', 'San Francisco'],
    "2": ['London', 'Cambridge'],
    "3": ['Paris', 'Nice']
}

$('#country').on('change', function() {
    var cities = cityMap[$(this).val()];
    $('#cities').empty().append(cities.map(function(city) {
        return $('<option />').text(city);
    }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option>Select a country</option>
  <option value="1">United states</option>
  <option value="2">United kingdom</option>
  <option value="3">France</option>
</select>

<select id="cities">
  <option value="">Select country first</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How to set value for child selection and that will be id not the city name?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question but you can make a function on the change :

```
$("#country").change(function(){
if($(this).val() == 2){
//United Kingdom selected
}else{
...
}
});
```

Comment: Can you please make your answer little details to understand, i am not good with js.

Answer (score 0):

Please find this snippet

```js
 $(function(){
    $("#country").on("change",function(){
    
    
    
    if($(this).val() == "0")
    {
    
    alert("Please select Country");
    }
    else
    {
    
    alert($(this).val());
    //do you rest of work for Country binding
    }
    });
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">United states</option>
<option value="2">United kingdom</option>
<option value="3">France</option>
</select>

<select id="country">
<option value="">Select country first</option>
</select>
```